# why 3 of punishment, 7 of consolation, 2 of repentance

Tags: number, calendar, haftarah

As is well known (e.g. from *Tosafos* to [*M'gila* 31:2](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1474&size=1) or from [*Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim* 428:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49626&st=&pgnum=190)), we have three *haftaros* of punishment, followed by seven of consolation and then two of return (repentance). Why these numbers specifically?

Comment: http://www.ou.org/yerushalayim/threeweeks/haftarot.htm

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about 2 of repentance, but about 3 of punishment and 7 consolation I've heard the following explanation from the lecture of [Rav Pinkus](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A1).

When we see a number 10 that is splited to 3 and 7 it means the cause and effect. The source if this is in *sfiros* (I don't undarstand that part much, but anyway) 3 high sfiros are the source and the rest 7 are derived from those 3.

Another example is in the following pasuk ([Dvorim 8:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%97/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93#.D7.96)): 
אֶרֶץ נַחֲלֵי מָיִם עֲיָנֹת וּתְהֹמֹת
those are 3 causes and the next pasuk is the famous  אֶרֶץ חִטָּה וּשְׂעֹרָה וְגֶפֶן וּתְאֵנָה וְרִמּוֹן אֶרֶץ זֵית שֶׁמֶן וּדְבָשׁ.
those are 7 effects.

From this the answer is obvious, we all know that 
כל המתאבל על ירושלים, זוכה ורואה בשמחתה
(The one who mourns about Jerusalem, would see her joy).
Hence 3 of punishment is the cause and 7 of consolation if the effect.

Comment: Nice (though it doesn't explain the two of repentance). Thanks. Who's Rav Punkus?

Comment: Sorry, my typo. I meant Rav Shimshon Pinkus: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A1

Comment: Sefirot are split into two: the 3 intellectual attributes (Wisdom, Understanding, and Knowledge) and the 7 emotional attribute. Kabbalistic thought explains that the intellect gives birth to emotions. See here for a discussion about the connection between the 3 intellectual and 7 emotional attributes and the 10 weeks of haftorahs: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2267/jewish/Seven-Degrees-of-Consolation.htm